# Whats the difference between OpenSSL and LetsEncrypt?

Tags: security, https, openssl, lets-encrypt

Historically we have used LetsEncrypt at work, but the nginx container we are using has Openssl installed on it already.

What are different use cases for selecting OpenSSL or Lets Encrypt?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Go ahead and google this question and youll get no answers.

Comment: [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) and [Let's Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) are two *very* different things.  You'll want to google each of them separately, because this question is similar to "What's the difference between an airplane and a jet engine?"

Comment: So that would be the simple answer to the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" With all due respect,  this is a question about programming and development according to the SO Help Center.

Comment: I think if the question was phrased differently to express the intent better, then it would fit this site, as this is exactly why I'm here right now : "What is the difference between commands 'openssl req -x509' where certs are saved into a folder like /etc/ssl/private, and 'certbot certonly' which saves to /etc/letsencrypt/live? " Yes, this is a programming question because I need to evaluate two scripts that seemingly do the same thing, and I'm not sure if one of these code blocks should be deprecated or modified to more closely agree with the other.

Comment: 1. **OpenSSL**:
   - Creates self-signed certificates.
   - Not trusted by browsers.
   - User-defined validity.
   - Free and manual management.
   - Good for testing and internal use.

2. **Let's Encrypt**:
   - Certificate Authority issuing trusted certificates.
   - Browser-trusted, 90-day validity.
   - Free with automation via tools like `certbot`.
   - Suitable for public web content.

Use OpenSSL for internal/testing and Let's Encrypt for public, trusted sites.

Comment: 18k views for this question, proving that there are many people with the same question. But some people think they are good, criticize and downplay such a worthy question. what a shame

Answer (score 45, accepted):

LetsEncrypt is a free certificate authority.  OpenSSL is a software package for generating certificates.  The LetsEncrypt scripts use OpenSSL to generate certificates and sign them with the LetsEncrypt service.

Comment: Is there any official document about this?

Comment: I mean is there any official document that says `The LetsEncrypt scripts use OpenSSL to generate certificates and sign them with the LetsEncrypt service.`

Comment: Just look at the certbot scripts.  Should be fairly obvious.

Comment: What is certbot ?

Comment: @sofs1 certbot is the program that uses the letsencrypt infrastructure.

Comment: Amir is basically asking for references and he gets pushed back for it? Wow...

Comment: it's not "fairly obvious" to people who don't work on these every day...